# python patch with side_effect on Object's method is not called with self

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I encounter a surprising behaviour of the side_effect parameter in patch.object where the function replacing the original does not receive `self`

```py
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        self.noise = 'Woof'

    def make_noise(self):
        return self.noise

def loud(self):
    return self.noise.upper() + '!!'


from unittest.mock import patch

dog = Animal()
dog.make_noise()
with patch.object(Animal, 'make_noise', side_effect=loud):
    dog.make_noise()
```

This give:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/lustre/home/production/Applications/python/python-3.4.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 902, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/lustre/home/production/Applications/python/python-3.4.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 968, in _mock_call
    ret_val = effect(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: loud() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

If I change the `loud` function to

```
def loud(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

I get the following output:

```
()
{}
```

Is there a way to replace a function from an object and still receive self?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`self` is only supplied for *bound methods* (because functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)). A `Mock` object is not such a method, and the `side_effect` function is not bound, so `self` is indeed not going to be passed in.

If you *must* have access the instance in a `side_effect` object, you'll have to patch the function on the class with an actual function:

```
with patch.object(Animal, 'make_noise', new=loud):
```

Now `make_noise` is replaced by the `loud` function on the `Animal` class, so it'll be bound:

```
>>> with patch.object(Animal, 'make_noise', new=loud):
...     dog.make_noise()
...
'WOOF!!'
```

The alternative is to set `autospec=True`, at which point `mock` will use a real function to mock out `make_noise()`:

```
>>> with patch.object(Animal, 'make_noise', autospec=True, side_effect=loud):
...     dog.make_noise()
...
'WOOF!!'
```

Also see the [*Mocking Unbound Methods* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods) in the mock *getting started* section.

Comment: an important note here is that `new` is not a mocked function, so it lakes the niceties of call interception (call count, call args, etc..)

if you need to get these, use the last described solution here - autospec + side effect